# Simulating multiple mouse events

Tags: wpf, events, button, mouseover, mouseenter

I'm attempting to create a UI where I interact with normal WPF controls without the mouse. I want to support multiple cursors so using any regular input simulation (such as `SendInput`) doesn't work. I also tried interlacing `SendInput` messages to simulate to mouse cursors but that didn't work either (only got one mouse input). I also have the constraint that I do not want to use Windows `MultiPoint`.
I've tried sending events to the controls (testing it on Button) through mouse events when I detect my cursor position is above the controls using: `MouseEnterEvent`, `MouseLeaveEvent`, `MouseMove`, `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent`. But except for the `MouseDownEvent`, none of it seems to work.
Here is an example of how I send the `MouseEnterEvent`:

```
System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e =
    new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Input.Mouse.PrimaryDevice, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
e.RoutedEvent = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseEnterEvent;
elementUnderCursor.RaiseEvent(e);
```

Where `elementUnderCursor` is a `UIElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i wanted the same thing for my multimose kinect app be but if you have an emulated mouse driver you would just have to figure out how to tell the app that an event happened with that mouse driver instead of your usb mouse or ps/2 mouse driver.
For instance,
send the mousedown and up event to simulate mouse click for mouse #1,#2. Also, update mouse positon for mouse #1,#2. 
My reasoning for the above is i wanted it to work in any application by running a similar program to the above program in the background as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Update dsf works for simulating virtual mouse devices im working on a multiple mouse project with kinect so please look at the current progress at the  site: http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com.
be warned multiple mouse drivers cant be built overnight.
also, download the windows ddk to simulate the mouse devices. the testgenerichid.wsf script has to be changed for your scenario but its possible.